# Tastypie: change response only for CREATE and UPDATE

Tags: rest, tastypie

Is there any way to change the response that comes from server only for CREATE and UPDATE requests so it look like

```
{ "root": 
    [ { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", "field3": "value3", "id": 12 ],
"success": true }
```

instead of:

```
{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", "field3": "value3", "id": 12 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Take a look at the hooks:

```
alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data)
```

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#alter-list-data-to-serialize

and

```
alter_detail_data_to_serialize(self, request, data)
```

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#alter-detail-data-to-serialize

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom serializer to make it work:

```
class CustomJSONSerializer(Serializer):
    def to_json(self, data, options=None):
        options = options or {}
        data = self.to_simple(data, options)
        root = {}
        root['success'] = True
        if data.has_key('meta'):
            meta = data['meta']
            del data['meta']
            root.update(meta)
        objects = []
        if data.has_key('objects'):
            objects = data['objects']
            del data['objects']
        if not objects:
            objects = [data]
        root['root'] = objects
        return simplejson.dumps(root, cls=json.DjangoJSONEncoder, sort_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing I did with code like this

`class MyModel:
    class Meta:
        ...
    def alter_detail_data_to_serialize(self, request, to_be_serialized):
        return {"myRoot": to_be_serialized}`